# Reshaping a pandas dataframe from (12,1) to a specific shaped (3,4)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a specific reshaping I'm trying to accomplish. I don't see how to use np.reshape or pd.pivot to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
df = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]

#I would like the output to look like:

0  1  2  3
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
3  4  4  4
```

Comment: Try df.values.reshape(3,4)

Comment: pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(3,4).T) works. Thanks

Comment: FWIW `pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df, (4, -1), 'F'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [pandas.DataFrame.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) or [pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) with [numpy.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape)

> Per pandas documentation: Is recommended using `DataFrame.to_numpy()`

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

import pandas as pd 

list = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
df = pd.Series(list)

# Option1 using 'values' with reshape()
print('Option1 : \n', df.values.reshape(3,4).T)

# Option2 using 'to_numpy()' with reshape()
print('Option2 : \n',df.to_numpy().reshape(3,4).T)

# Get reshape dataframe to vector
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(3,4).T)

# dataframe to vector Option1 
print('Option1: Convert dataframe to vector: \n', np.reshape(df1.values.T, (1, df1.size)))

# dataframe to Option2
print('Option2: Convert dataframe to vector: \n', df1.to_numpy().T.reshape(1, df1.size))

# numpy array to vector :
df2 = df.to_numpy().reshape(3,4).T

print('Array to vector: \n', np.reshape(df2.T, (1, df2.size)))
```

> ```
> Out:
> Option1 :
>  [[1 1 1]
>  [2 2 2]
>  [3 3 3]
>  [4 4 4]]
> Option2 :
>  [[1 1 1]
>  [2 2 2]
>  [3 3 3]
>  [4 4 4]]
> Option1: Convert dataframe to vector:
>  [[1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4]]
> Option2: Convert dataframe to vector:
>  [[1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4]]
> Array to vector:
>  [[1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4]]
> ```

[See here interactive](https://repl.it/repls/FrugalWideGenre)

Comment: How would you go backwards. From a (3,4) to a (12,1):

From:
[[1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]
 [4 4 4]]

to a list

 [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]

Comment: Updated the code to include the “rollback”, feel free to ask if any other questions arise and if did help you can accept the answer.